# Configuring config/database.php file using php script

Tags: codeigniter, database-connection

I have a script in my controller which is as follows:

```
if($this->db->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_ecommerce"))
        {
                $sql=file_get_contents('./databse_backup/backup.sql');
                foreach (explode(";\n", $sql) as $sql) 
                {
                    $sql = trim($sql);
                    //echo  $sql.'<br/>============<br/>';
                        if($sql) 
                    {
                        $this->db->query($sql);
                    } 
                }  
        }
```

It creates a database and then runs a backup sql file.

My issue is that we need to configure the config/database.php file beforehand.

First I want this script to run and after that the database.php file should be changed.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_name';
```

Since its now for localhost hence,

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_name';
```

Comment: So after you import the database, you want to update your ```database.php``` file to match your localhost?

Answer (score 2):

An approach would be to have 'template file' in your installation folder like:
ex. database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '<?php echo $hostname;?>';
$db['default']['username'] = '<?php echo $username;?>';
$db['default']['password'] = '<?php echo $password;?>';
$db['default']['database'] = '<?php echo $database;?>';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '<?php echo $prefix;?>';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and then you can get the values for db connection (from a form for example) and write the new file in your codeigniter application (application/config/database.php)

ex.

```
$settings['hostname']   = $this->input->post('hostname');
$settings['username']   = $this->input->post('username');
$settings['password']   = $this->input->post('password');
$settings['database']   = $this->input->post('database');
$settings['prefix']     = $this->input->post('prefix');     

$file_contents      = $this->load->view('templates/database', $settings, true);


write_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'application/config/database.php', $file_contents);
```